# bootstrap fluid layout spans, floating issue, white space at top issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

Please help, I'm at my wits end after two hours of struggling!
http://www.tumblrating.com/choose.aspx?blog=nevver

The issue is I want the breadcrumbs box to go stretch the way to the "fun mode" box, but then shrink when you shrink the window

I got it to at least float left after much struggle... but now when you resize the page there is white space at the top (!!)

Can someone expert in bootstrap/css please help?

**EDIT::**

On the off chance someone having trouble with fluid bootstrap stumbles here:

An IMPORTANT thing I had forgotten is that within each nested div the spans have to add up to 12 rather than just adding up to the parent (the way it is for fixed). For instance div class="span3" still needs two div class="span6" 's inside it to add up to 12 (100%).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have padding-top:60px set for body in choose.aspx, and while the navbar has `position:fixed` it looks ok, but bootstrap's responsive css makes it `position:static` for screens narrower than 979px, and body's padding makes this effect.

You should either set `.navbar:fixed` to override bootstrap's responsive rule, or add css media query to make `padding-top:0px` for body when screen is narrower than 979px, at the same place where you make it 60

so in choose.aspx where you set body styles:

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
//+ add this
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it, Thanks so much for looking

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is inside the div "span12" (class="span12") which is set to 100% width. By arbitrarily placing a color border that you can later remove you can see the area that it covers.

Inside you have "span8 pull-left" which wraps your bread crumb gray bar and "span4" which holds the Fun Mode elements.

Before trying any fix please remove every property you set inline or with the "!important" tag because they will overwrite whatever you do next and it will be difficult to find out the exact numeric values you need to make this work.

Set the borders of these 2 inner divs to different colors for debugging purposes. Float "span8 pull-left" to the left and "span4" to the right in your css file (note that you have to find out which tags and which lines are referencing them in your css file with the developers tool; I have a mobile device which is why I am not giving you the line because it might not be the one you need). Add a clear html element after the closing tag of "span4" and before the closing tag of your "span12" holder like this,

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

This is a hack but it works better than adding the clear directly in the css.

Then play with the margins and the widths of both inner divs until you achieve your needs to a 100% width. Example, set the left div to 80% and the right div to 20% width. Make sure you remove padding in any of the inner divs and instead play with the margins. Padding is read very differently by every browser and it can cause great headaches when playing with compatibility.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! This was so helpful & well written The bordered colors were a great idea. It allowed me to see that the div was indeed going all the way even though the breadcrumbs werent. I think I figured it out. Thanks again!